# Why my solution to Array Rotation seems right but shows wrong on Leetcode?

Tags: python, arrays

I'm doing Leetcode #189 which is array rotation. I decide to do this by splitting the array into two arrays and join them.

Following is my code:

```
class Solution(object):
    def rotate(self, nums, k):
        """
        :type nums: List[int]
        :type k: int
        :rtype: None Do not return anything, modify nums in-place instead.
        """
        
        num1 = []
        num2 = []
        
        for i in range(0, len(nums)-k):
            num1.append(nums[i])
            
        for j in range(len(nums)-k, len(nums)):
            num2.append(nums[j])
            
        num2.extend(num1)
        print(num2)
```

but my output is wrong on Leetcode but right on Pycharm. Why? Is there anything wrong in the code?

Comment: from the autofill of the class in your code example "None Do not return anything, modify nums in-place instead." did you try doing that instead of printing num2?

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen I tried nums = num2.extend(num1) and print(nums). But still doesn't work.

Comment: that overrides the reference, `nums[:] = num2` or more clearly `nums.clear(); nums.extend(num2)` would modify in place.

Answer (score 0):

The question asks to do a rotation in place, and not return anything. You created new arrays which were thrown away.

Also a note on the solution, you could just `pop` and `insert` values into `nums` for the required number of rotations:

```
nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
k = 3

for i in range(k % len(nums)):
    nums.insert(0, nums.pop())

print(nums)
```

```
[5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Another option is to slice assign to the variable using `nums[:]`

```
nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
k = 3

k %= len(nums)
nums[:] = nums[-k:] + nums[:-k]

print(nums)
```

Comment: it shows "time limit exceed" after submitting.